# How to convert $((A\lor B)\land ((B\leftrightarrow A)\rightarrow C))\lor(C\rightarrow \lnot A)$ into CNF.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I started off with:

$$((A\lor B)\land ((B\leftrightarrow A)\rightarrow C))\lor(C\rightarrow \lnot A)$$

And I've managed to get to:

$$((A\lor B) \land (((B\land \lnot A) \lor (A \land \lnot B)) \lor C)) \lor (\lnot C \lor \lnot A)$$

How do I finish and get this into CNF?

Comment: Don't you mean $B\wedge\lnot A$?

Comment: Typo?  That should be $((A\lor B) \land (((B\land\lnot A) \lor (A \land \lnot B)) \lor C)) \lor (\lnot C \lor \lnot A)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp You're right, fixed the typo thanks

Comment: *right sorry for being a grammar nazi

Comment: Since there are only 3 variables, have you considered making a truth table?

Comment: Keep distributing any $\lor$'s over any $\land$'s .. patience my friend!

Comment: Here's a hint on this, building on Alon's comment: start off by making a truth table. There are perhaps other ways to proceed here, but this is perhaps the 'purest' way to do so and it guarantees the correct answer. The CNF is, obviously, an 'and' of 'or' terms. So, look at all of the 'true' rows of the truth table: what combinations of truth values generate this expression? Construct those, and then 'and' them together; the result is the CNF.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\neg(A\leftrightarrow B)$ $\equiv (A\wedge\neg B)\vee(\neg A\wedge B)\\ \equiv (A\vee B)\wedge(\neg A\vee\neg B) $

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $\lnot (A\wedge C)$, this expression is true, so we don't need to consider the other expression. Hence, we only need to consider the larger clause for the case that $(A\wedge C)$ is true.

Hence, $(A\vee B)$ is always true, so a true statement conjuncted with another statement is logically equivalent to that other statement.

So, so far we have

$$((B\land \lnot A) \lor (A \land \lnot B)) \lor C) \lor (\lnot C \lor \lnot A)$$

Next, note that under our assumption that $C$ is true, we know that the inner expression is a clause disjuncted into $C$, which means it is always true.

Hence, this expression can never be not true. The simplest CNF that could be made for this expression is $(C\vee\lnot C)$.